# Is angular material2 having col-md-4 something like that?

Tags: angular, angular-material

These days, im trying to playground of Angular 2 and material. Before that I used PrimeNG but I changed to Angular Material.
But I couldn't find where is the classes for changing width such as col-md-4 something like that ?
Angular material 2 web is so weak of example and descriptions....

Is there any good web for knowing angular material UI???

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Angular 2 material library have grids and layouts. Have a look at : https://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list

There is an example of the grid with 4 columns:

```
<md-grid-list cols="4">
  <md-grid-tile>Column 1</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>Column 2</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>Column 3</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>Column 4</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```